# IShockwaveFlashEvents: how to handle getURL("javascript:?

Tags: c++, flash, activex, adobe

I wrote a simple WinAPI application in C++ which embeds the Abode Flash ActiveX control. It works fine.

Next task that i have to do it is handle `getURL("javascript:somefoo(someparam)", "")`in C++

I don't understand the right way to do this. I create connection point to listen to `_IShockwaveFlashEvents` and my `STDMETHODIMP Invoke(...)` was called 3 times(!)
but I still don't understand how to get the params of `getURL...`

And after calling `getURL()`. IE starts. How do I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question.

1. you cannot handle getURL
2. flash must use fscommand to pass data to host application